# Вывести ноль вместо пустой строки в запросе

Tags: sql

Есть запрос, который выводит номер отдела магазина и сумму товаров, проданных в нем. Проблема в том, что если сумма равна 0, то этот отдел не выводится вообще, то есть нет строки №отдела - '0'. Попробовал так -

```sql
 CASE 
 WHEN SUM(total) IS NULL 
 THEN '0'
 END SUM(total)
```

не получилось.
Можете подсказать еще варианты?

**UPDATE (перенесено из комментария):**

```
USE laba1 

SELECT DEPARTMENT.department_id [отдел], SUM(SALES_ORDER.total) [сумма] 
FROM SALES_ORDER 
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER ON SALES_ORDER.customer_id = CUSTOMER.customer_id 
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE ON CUSTOMER.salesperson_id = EMPLOYEE.employee_id 
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT ON EMPLOYEE.department_id = DEPARTMENT.department_id 
WHERE order_date BETWEEN '19881231' AND '19900101' 
  AND DEPARTMENT.department_id = 14 
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT.department_id
```

Comment: Если нет самой строки, то надо разбираться не с обработкой результата запроса, а с условиями связывания таблиц и выборки данных, т.к. строка в принципе потеряна из результата где-то на этом этапе.

Comment: @Akina 
`
USE laba1
SELECT DEPARTMENT.department_id [отдел], SUM(SALES_ORDER.total) [сумма]
FROM SALES_ORDER INNER JOIN
CUSTOMER ON SALES_ORDER.customer_id = CUSTOMER.customer_id INNER JOIN 
EMPLOYEE ON CUSTOMER.salesperson_id = EMPLOYEE.employee_id INNER JOIN
DEPARTMENT ON EMPLOYEE.department_id = DEPARTMENT.department_id

WHERE order_date BETWEEN '19881231' AND '19900101'
AND DEPARTMENT.department_id = 14

GROUP BY DEPARTMENT.department_id
`

Comment: Замените внутреннее связывание на левое. И самой левой сделайте ту таблицу (DEPARTMENT), все записи из которой должны присутствовать в выводе. *если сумма равна 0* - неверно, только если по данному отделу вообще нет продаж в указанный период.

Comment: + `SUM(case when SALES_ORDER.total is null then '0' else SALES_ORDER.total end)`

Comment: Во-первых, у вас не пустая строка, а отсутствие строки. Во-вторых, `CASE WHEN A IS NULL THEN B ELSE A END` равносильно `COALESCE(A, B)`